# Step functions convert string to number

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Is there a way in an aws step function to convert a string to a number?

I have a query param that is passed from api gateway to the step function. It is a string with a numeric value. I would like to cast the string to a number in the step function state language, but so far no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a native solution for Step Functions to achieve this yet.
Another workaround would be to use a simple lambda to convert the type.

Edit: A native workaround would be to use the intrinsic function `States.StringToJson`

e.g.

```
"NumberValue.$": "States.StringToJson("$.numberAsString")"
```